# Is it possible to rename a folder in Nuget

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'm creating a `nuget` package to install some `ascx` files into a solution. The folder i want the ascx files to be stored in will be different depending on the project. IE folder name will be the same as the project name.

Is it possible to have a pop up to capture text so I can rename the folder in the content section of a nuget package during install. Is it then possible to add this folder name to the namespace of the files within the folder?

I know its possible to add `$rootnamespace$` with a `.pp extension` to replace the key with the correct root namespace, but can you append to this too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ought to look into the options for [Automatically Running PowerShell Scripts During Package Installation and Removal](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Automatically_Running_PowerShell_Scripts_During_Package_Installation_and_Removal).